# Do modelforms in Django require the forms to have the forms.fieldtype format? form.save() not working for multipleupload

Tags: python, django, forms

I am using the django-multiupload app found at https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload.

This appears to work well but I was using a modelform previously and replaced my prior form field with a widget with their default multipupload field.

This doesn't seem to have a formfield for modelforms. Would my form still function in the same way?

It seems that the form.save() function is not acting accordingly, I get this error:

```
Traceback: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/Users/agatorano/Code/metascape/metascape.org/source/uploads/views.py" in new_page
  81.     form.save(for_page=sess_) File "/Users/agatorano/Code/metascape/metascape.org/source/uploads/forms.py" in save
  43.     return super().save() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  457.                              construct=False) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_instance
  103.         instance.save() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  590.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  618.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  699.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  732.                                using=using, raw=raw) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  921.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  919.             for sql, params in self.as_sql(): File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  877.                 for obj in self.query.objs File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  877.                 for obj in self.query.objs File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  875.                     for f in fields File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
  299.         if file and not file._committed:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /list/new Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

I know that this has to do with the fact multiple files are being saved in the form, but I don't know a solution.

my form:

```
from django import forms
from uploads.models import Document,Sess
from multiupload.fields import MultiFileField

from pandas_sql import *

class DocumentForm(forms.models.ModelForm):

  #docfile = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={
  #  'class':'filestyle','data-classButton':"btn btn-primary",
  #  'data-input':"false",'data-classIcon':"icon-plus",
  #  'data-buttonText':"Upload Data",}))

  docfile = MultiFileField(min_num=1, max_num=3, max_file_size=1024*1024*5)

  is_multiple = forms.BooleanField(label='Multi-Gene List',required=False,widget=forms.CheckboxInput()) 

  class Meta:
    model=Document
    fields=('docfile','is_multiple',)

  def clean_docfile(self):
    docfile = self.cleaned_data.get('docfile',False)
    name = docfile.name
    extension = os.path.splitext(name)[1]

    if extension != '.xls' and extension != '.xlsx':
      raise forms.ValidationError("only excel files allowed ")

    if docfile._size<int("27000"):
      raise forms.ValidationError("File Not Large Enough For Upload")

    return docfile

def save(self,for_page):
    self.instance.sess = for_page
    return super().save()
```

and here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Sess(models.Model):

  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('view_page',args=[self.id])

class Document(models.Model):

  docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
  is_multiple = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  sess = models.ForeignKey(Sess,default=None)
```

The commented part was my prior code. Do I need to revert my form file to a standard form file or does a modelform still work? Thank you

Comment: Your usage of modelform seems a bit odd to me. Rather than redifining `docfile` and `is_multiple` in it, which are clearly model's fields, I would only change their widgets or whatever property is necessary. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields and tell me how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem it turns out was that the form.save() function couldn't handle creating multiple model objects with the multiple.

I had to manually create each model object for each file in the list of files.

So I think modelForms were not appropriate in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

`MultiFileField` is for uploading more than one file at once and your model (which you didn't post) obviously has a single file field. There's a clear example of how to use `MultiFileField` with a model having a single file field [in the doc](https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload#usage)

Comment: I am sorry for not posting my model!

I am not having issue with my model matching up with the form, but instead whether the fact I am using a formmodel instead of a standard form is appropriate

Comment: I am specifically having trouble with the form.save() function.